# Notation question, random variable is in $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What does it mean, that random variable $X\in \mathcal{I}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is $\sigma$-algebra of events, such that $P(A)=P(\varphi ^{-1}(A))$ for some function $\varphi$?

I haven't seen before notation that random variable belongs to a sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on some set $\Omega$ and $X$ is a mapping $X:\Omega\to\mathcal{R}$, the notation $X\in\mathcal{F}$ usually means that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, such that $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{F}$ for all Borel measurable sets $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

So in particular, in your case, $X\in\mathcal{I}$ simply means that $X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{I}$.